# Will the write pointers in drive-managed SMR drives ever be reset?

Tags: hard-drive

I own a Seagate Expansion Desktop 5TB external hard drive, containing a ST5000DM000 according to `hdparm`. While information found on the internet is inconclusive, I strongly suspect that this drive utilizes [shingled magnetic recording](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingled_magnetic_recording) -- the I/O patterns I am observing can hardly be explained otherwise. Obviously, it is of the drive-managed variety, and is therefore transparent to the user (and the OS).

Reading up on the technology, I found that for the upcoming host-managed (and, in part, host-aware) types, every zone of the drive will have an associated write pointer, and the device driver and file system will have to always continue writing to a zone at that position. Alternatively, to completely rewrite a zone, the write pointer can be reset to the beginning. I assume that drive-managed SMR drives work on the same principle, with the drive controller managing the zone accesses. Any write that does not happen to fall on the write pointer will be put to the random-access persistent cache first, thus preserving the speed in most cases.

However, since the OS does not know that this is an SMR drive (and even if it were to correctly guess, it would not know where the zone boundaries are), it has no way to tell the drive to reset the write pointer for a zone. As soon as a zone is filled for the first time, any subsequent write command (that does not happen to write the entire zone at once) will trigger a read-modify-write cycle. At least, that's my hypothesis for why I cannot transfer a contiguous 100-GB file without the speed grinding to single-digit MB/s after the first 20-or-so GB. (It is most probably writing to a region of the drive previoiusly occupied by a large file that has since been deleted.)

So, does anyone know, or has anyone even wondered if there is any way to tell a drive-managed SMR drive that a particular region does not contain any useful data anymore, and can safely be partially overwritten without going through the cache first? (I could imagine a Security Erase to trigger that, but that is hardly something one does routinely.)

Comment: Some new Seagate drives showed up which support the TRIM commands. Tried trimming but whole device, but the data remained.